# to compare two rows of same deal having two different version in same table and find nonmatching column -sql

Tags: sql

Table 1:

```
DEAL ID,
VERSION ID,
QTE,
datemodified,
systemdate,
......
```

like this so many columns are there.

Inputs:

```
DEALID,VERSIONID,DATEMODIFIED,SYSTEMDATE, QTE,SECURITIES
177     0         13-10-2016    13-10-2016   50    DD
177     1         13-10-2016     13-10-2016   100   DD
177     2          13-10-2016    13-10-2016   100    YY
```

Output:

I should tell which column is changed in each version

For deal ID `177` columns changed according to `SYSTEMDATE= QTE,SECURITIES`

Comment: Which DBMS you are using

Comment: it is 11.1.1.4.37

Comment: please help me to solve this

Comment: That is not `DBMS` it is version of your DBMS . Tell your DBMS name

Comment: oracle-sql developer

Comment: someone suggest a idea on this pls.thanks in advance